# How to access the SharePoint REST apis via auth0

Tags: azure, sharepoint, oauth, azure-active-directory, auth0

I want to access the **SharePoint** list in a single page application using the **SharePoint REST (OData) APIs.** I tried to enable the SSO using Azure directory so I can access the SharePoint but I can access SharePoint in the browser. But I want to access SP via rest API, **is it possible in Auth0 to get the SharePoint access token to read SP REST APIS?**